# How to close a specific name pdf document by using vba in excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am operating on excel to control open and close a pdf document by VBA. I can open a unique pdf document by using the below code

```
ExeFilepath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader 2015\Reader\AcroRd32.exe "
Filepath = "C:\Work\example.pdf"
Shell(ExeFilepath & Filepath, vbMaximizedFocus)
```

By using code above I can open the named "example.pdf" successfuly.
But when I want to close the unique pdf document I opened I use the shell command

`Shell "taskkill /F /IM AcroRd32.exe"`

The shell command can close the pdf, but it will close all the pdf document I opened regardless of whether I open it manually or by the VBA code.

**My question is how to close a unique pdf document but do nothing to the other pdf I already opened?**

Answer (score 0):

What if you assign the shell command to a variable like this:

```
dim pid as variant
pid = Shell(ExeFilepath & Filepath, vbMaximizedFocus)
```

and then close it like that:

```
call shell("taskkill /F /PID " & Cstr(pid))
```

Comment: I tried but seems not to work   call shell("taskkill /F /PID " & Cstr(pid))

Comment: dim pid as variant